# How to get sum of distinct ids/elements in a column Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm having a '**results**' table shown below:

[image]

there is column 'quiz_id' having two ids 1 & 2 repeating two times, I want to get sum all the distinct quiz_id/s and then want to display the value in different table.

using:

```
$countQuizPlayed = DB::table('results')->pluck('quiz_id')->groupby('quiz_id');
```

Here is table where I want to display values ('quizzes' table):

```
<thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>#</th>
                                  <th>Name</th>
                                  <th>Ctaegory</th>
                                  <th>Count</th>
                                  <th>Sub Category</th>
                                  <th>Prepaed By</th>
                                  <th>Maximum Time</th>
                                  <th>Played</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody  class="searchable">

                                @if(count($allquizzes)>0)

                                @foreach($allquizzes as $key=>$quiz)
                                
                                <tr>
                                  <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$quiz->qname}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$quiz->description}}</td>

                                  <td>

                                    @if($countQuizPlayed = $quiz->id)
                                    
                                    {{$countQuizPlayed}}

                                    @endif
                                    
                                  </td>

                                  <td>{{$quiz->subcategory}}</td>
                                  <td><a href="{{$quiz->profileUrl}}">{{$quiz->by}}</a></td>
                                  {{--  @foreach($visitors as $visitor)
                                    <td>
                                     <a href="/profile/{{$visitor->id}}">
                                      {{$visitor->name}}
                                    </a>
                                    </td>
                                    @endforeach --}}
                                  <td>{{$quiz->minutes}}</td>
```

I want:

[image]

**Note**: Quiz **Name**:3 hasn't played by any user yet so its count is "0" as not present in "results" table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and post text not images

Comment: Based on the details, this question has nothing to do with sum or distinct. You seem to need a left join and a count.

Comment: Then what should I do sir? @Shadow

Comment: you need to do left join with parent table i.e. quiz table

Comment: @DaljitSingh check out the answer to the duplicate question.